# Intl.DateTimeFormat Month "Short" with Period

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to add a period after the abbreviated 'short' month name when using Intl.DateTimeFormat?

If possible, I'd also prefer the more common `en-us` month abbreviation `Sept.` rather than `Sep` or `Sep.`

```
var dateStr = '2015-09-22';
var dateObj = new Date(dateStr);
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(dateObj);

// outputs: Sep 22, 2015
// better: Sep. 22, 2015
// preferred: Sept. 22, 2015
```

Comment: Don't use the Date constructor to parse strings, it's implementation dependent and the format YYYY-MM-DD will be treated in 3 different ways by browsers in use: some as UTC (which may mean the date changes by 1 day depending on timezone), some as local and the rest NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dependent on the system's Regional Settings or locale, which the script or the script author **doesn't** have control of. Well, you can do an i18n on this:

```
monthsShort= 'Jan_Feb_Mar_Apr_May_Jun_Jul_Aug_Sep_Oct_Nov_Dec'.split('_')
               .map(function (month) {
                 return month + ".";
               });
```

BTW, I haven't seen anywhere saying *Janu.* or *Febu.* LoL.

Comment: Thanks - I like the split approach

Comment: Surely you're kidding. The split and map function is more characters and way more processing than an array literal with dots after the month abbreviations. The equivalent is: `['Jan.','Feb.','Mar.','Apr.','May.','Jun.','Jul.','Aug.','Sep.','Oct.','Nov.','Dec.']`.

Comment: You're obviously more likely to see _Febr_ than _Febu_.

Comment: I don't quite understand or get you @6infinity8

Comment: I was joking from the fact that _Febuary_ is not the correct spelling. _Febr_ is not uncommon, but for sure you'll never see _Febu_ (unless, perhaps, as a contracted form, although very unlikely).

Comment: @6infinity8 Haha, I get it. I felt the same.

Answer (score 1):

A small function can be used to reformat the date string. This avoids any issues with parsing and timezones and means you can use any form of abbreviation and periods:

```js
function reformatDateString(s) {
      var months = ['Jan.','Feb.','Mar.','Apr.','May.','Jun.','Jul.','Aug.','Sep.','Oct.','Nov.','Dec.'];
      var parts = s.split('-');
      return months[parts[1] - 1] + ' ' + Number(parts[1]) + ', ' + parts[0];
}

document.write(reformatDateString('2015-09-15')); // Sep. 9, 2015
```